# Slow sudo and ssmtp (hosts file problem)

Tags: 12.04, sudo, webserver, hosts

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS and when I type `sudo su` it takes 30+ seconds to open  the shell. Searching on internet, this problem seems related to the file `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`.

This isn't really a problem for me to wait, however this is affecting other programs (especially sSMTP wich I use for sending mails from PHP) and Apache is giving the classical "*could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name*".

So I've checked the hosts file and corrected it, and now the apache error is gone but the other problems persist. `sudo su` now takes about 10-15 seconds.

Output of `uname -n`, `hostname` and `hostname -f` is:

```
server.example.com
```

Output of `hostname -a`:

```
server
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1   server.example.com      server

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This server has a public IPv4 address and the DNS record for `server.example.com` is correct.

If I try `ping server` or `ping server.example.com` they work as expected (resolving to `127.0.1.1`)

I've run many servers in the past and this is the only one having this problem. I'm completely stuck, any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1**: the server is also running openvpn with less than 10 clients, but disabling the service has no consequences

**Update 2**: things tried so far:

1) Changing hostname to "localhost": this solves the problem, but isn't acceptable;

2) This version of `/etc/hosts` (not working):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost   server.example.com
127.0.1.1   server.example.com      server

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback   server.example.com
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

3) Current version of `/etc/hosts` (not working):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       server.sistema3.it      server

::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback    localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: is only `sudo su` affected or does the other commands take time too?

Comment: Got a try with `$ sudo echo -e "test"` and it runs immediately... so yes, only `sudo su` takes forever :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem, and it wasn't a server issue.

It was a setting in the client, Putty. X11 Forwarding was enabled, and caused all the issues. Switched that off.

I noticed that beacuse when connecting from another computer, it wasn't slow. Then I messed a bit with Putty, and bingo.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your /etc/hosts as follows :

```
 127.0.0.1   server.example.com 
 127.0.1.1   server.example.com      server

 ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback     server.example.com
 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Try executing `sudo su` now and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: nope, no effect :( I've updated my original question

Comment: Try switching your hostname to localhost by typing : `sudo hostname localhost` and check again.

Comment: yep. changing that to localhost solves the delay. going back to server.example.com reintroduces the problem

Comment: I've edited the answer. I've replaced the additional words with localhost. Try it out. Can you please update the question with your current hosts file?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Comment: I think I have a solution. Replace `localhost` with `server.example.com` everywhere. answer edited, yet again.

Comment: nope, not working. At this point I'm thinking this isn't a "hosts" file problem, however I have no clue how to diagnose this

Comment: Try this : `sudo strace -r -o trace.log sudo echo hi`.

It will show you what takes up your valuable time. Append it's output to the question.

Comment: the problem is that this command runs immediately without any delay!

Comment: execute : `sudo tcpdump -nvvv -i wlan0 port 53`. 

Replace 'wlan0' with the name of your active interface. 

With tcpdump running, run `sudo su` and check to see if there is any output from tcpdump. If there is, especially if there is only an outgoing request a no incoming response, then you should double-check /etc/hosts again.

Comment: done. I read some of the domains I host on that server. I waited for things to calm a little (there was some activity on the server) and thne executed `sudo su` on another terminal: no activity during the delay. Trying again with loopback interface...

Comment: Nothing on the `lo` interface

Comment: try installing gksu using `sudo apt-get install gksu` and see if the problem exists. if you don't know, gksu is just a frontend for running apps as superuser.

Comment: `gksu` is already installed on my system, however this is a server and I'm connected to it by ssh, I have no physical access. It won't run without an X session started

Comment: I am out of ideas. Maybe, [this](http://superuser.com/questions/446915/why-do-password-entries-over-ssh-take-so-long) link will interest you?